# Is it something wrong in proof of Preservation of Collision Resistance for Merkle-Damgard?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I wonder about this proof. Can someone help me?

I try to prove for Presevation of Collision Resistance for Merkle-Damgard as guide in end of this paper ([Security Reductions of the Second Round SHA-3
Candidates](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/381.pdf)).

Assume H is Merkle-Damgard hash function, f is an compression, f' = chop_s(f). I try to prove:
〖Adv〗_H^col (q)≤ 〖Adv〗_f'^col (q)
However, I think it may be is
〖Adv〗_H^col (q)≤ 〖Adv〗_f'^col (q)+〖Adv〗_f^col (q) + ..
Because collision with not only in one position (i) of f, it may be collision in f', and some position f.
Can someone explain for me why?

Comment: please typeset those horrible equations using MathJax/LaTex. Or tell us where exactly in that long document they are.

Comment: @user80059 Please render your equations using MathJax/LaTex.  If you do, you are likely to get an answer.